# WPF - Two list view row synchronization on mouse hover

Tags: wpf

i have two list view in my wpf application splitted by a gridspiltter. i need to synchronize the mouse hover effect between this two list view.

```
<ListView datasrource="Dummy" x:name="list1"/>
<gridsplitter/>
<ListView datasource="Dummy" x:name="list2"/>
```

So if i am on row4 for list1  i need to give light blue background on the row mouse hovered over the list view item and sync the corresponding list view item in another list view i.e list2 with the same light blue background.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: If both ListViews are bound to the same data just bind both selected items to the same object

Comment: selected item binding will work only when i select that particular row,but in my case i need to change the background on mouse hover of that listview item